# How to convert a string into an array in bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to convert a string into an array and loop that array to pass each value as a parameter to a bash command. I am getting bad substitution message when I execute the scripts.

```
text = 'xdc','cde','erd','ded','ded','kie';
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=',';
ids=$($text);
for (i=0; i<${#ids[@]}; ++i);
do
echo "$i"
done
IFS=$OIFS
```

This the script I have written, also how to pass the index value as a parameter to a command inside the for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by using the array index value as a parameter? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to remove the text from around the assignment of the string variable:

```
text="'xdc','cde','erd','ded','ded','kie';"
```

Then you can just use the array form of the bash `read` command:

```
IFS=, read -a ids <<< "${text%;}"
```

where the `${text%;}` substitution removes the trailing semicolon. Note that, this way, the IFS is not modified outside of the `read` command so there's no need to save and restore it.

Your C-style for-loop syntax is almost correct, except that in bash, the loop needs double parentheses e.g.

```
for ((i=0; i<${#ids[@]}; ++i)); do printf '%s\n' "${ids[i]}"; done
```

Alternatively, you can loop over array members directly using a `for ... in` loop:

```
for i in "${ids[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
```

Comment: thanks for your answr.. I tried the above but i get Bad substitution

Comment: @Jes which line specifically gives the bad substitution? are you sure you are running the everything with bash not sh?

Comment: for i in "${ids[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done

Comment: @Jes hmm... don't know why that wouldn't work - sorry

Answer (score 1):

This will echo all of the items in your initial string, ensure that there is no space next to the `=` in `text=`, and use double quotes around the string. Also you're using unnecessary `;`s throughout your code.

```
#!/bin/bash

text="'xdc','cde','erd','ded','ded','kie'"

IFS=',' read -ra ids <<< "$text"

for i in "${ids[@]}"
do
echo "$i"
done
```

This will output

```
'xdc'
'cde'
'erd'
'ded'
'ded'
'kie'
```

Comment: how to wrap the string with double quotes in code.

Comment: Just type them.

Comment: No .. the string is not manually created, its from another PHP script that i am passing to bash .